# Android textview in 'return new' alertdialog

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

I've got code that looks like this:

```
    case 2:
            final TextView scoretext = new TextView (this);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("How cold or hot do you feel today?")
            .setView(qolscorelayout)
            .setPositiveButton("Confirm",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                    {
                        SeekBar qolDialogSeekbar = (SeekBar)qolscorelayout.findViewById(R.id.qolscore_seekbar);
                        todayScore = qolDialogSeekbar.getProgress();
                        showDialog(3);
                    }
                }
            ).create();
```

qolscorelayout is defined earlier as:

```
    qolscorelayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qolscore_dialog, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.qolscore_dialog_root_element)); //Layout for getting Seekbar in Dialog
```

I want a TextView inside the dialogue, though, just above the slider.

I was thinking about doing something like:

```
    case 2:
            final TextView scoretext = new TextView (this); //NEW
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("How cold or hot do you feel today?")
            .setView(qolscorelayout)
            .setPositiveButton("Confirm",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                    {
                        SeekBar qolDialogSeekbar = (SeekBar)qolscorelayout.findViewById(R.id.qolscore_seekbar);
                        todayScore = qolDialogSeekbar.getProgress();
                        scoretext.setText("" + todayScore); //NEW
                        showDialog(3);
                    }
                }
            ).create();
```

But how do I get it to put that TextView inside the dialog?

Comment: Why can't you just put a textview in qolscore_layout?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: Can you post your XML layout file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to what was already said.

Put the textview in the qolscore_layout. Then you can modify it's content like this:

```
qolscorelayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qolscore_dialog, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.qolscore_dialog_root_element));
final TextView scoretext = (TextView) qolscorelayout.findViewById(R.id.scoretext);
scoretext.setText("" + todayScore); //NEW
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I've realised thought that I want the textView to change on the seekbar being altered, not confirm clicked. I think I need to use a OnSeekBarChangeListener - but how could I implement it with my code as above?

Comment: Just as you said. Implement OnSeekBarChangeListener and modify the textView on OnProgressChanged.
Move the SeekBar init statement outside of the alertDialogBuilder, to the same place where you declare the textView, then just add the OnSeekBarChangeListener